# How to solve the " ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Tags: python

```
import os
#find all text files into data set folder
inputs = []
for file in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\code"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
       inputs.append(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\code" , file))
# concatenate all txt files in a file called merged_file.txt
with open('merged_file.txt', 'w') as f:
      for fname in inputs:
          with open(fname, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as infile:
              outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: In your last line, you're referring to a file object called `outfile` when you previously opened one called `f`. Try renaming them to match eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your code you have opened `merged_file.txt` as `f` but then when you try to write in that file, you have done `outfile.write()`. So you should name opened file `outfile` as well:

```
with open('merged_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      for fname in inputs:
          with open(fname, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as infile:
              outfile.write(infile.read())
              # Better to have this line too:
              # outfile.write('\n')
```